# Z-Score Formula Variation

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, z-statistic

When does one use the denominator $\sigma$ over the denominator $\sigma /\sqrt{n}$?  Why are there two separate forms and why does one look exactly like the t-score?  Do some authors just call both t and z scores z scores?

Comment: Please tell us what you mean by $\sigma$: is it a known standard deviation or an estimated standard deviation? Could you also please clarify the distinction you are making between "z score" (a standard term) and "t score" (not so standard: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_density#T-score for instance).

Comment: Sorry, it is a known standard deviation for the population.  While this is never known in practice from what I understand it is often 'given'.  To my knowledge both t and z scores use this rather than a sample variance, no?

Comment: On the contrary: a z-score typically uses a sample standard deviation $s$ unless the underlying standard deviation $\sigma$ is already assumed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on *what* is the z-score being tested for:

- If the 'x' is a data point (like an out-of-sample or out-of-time observation), then use $\sigma$ .
- If the 'x' is a statistic  (like mean of a few out-of-sample observation**s**) then use $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.

I got the clarification from this [beautiful document (pdf)](http://www.d.umn.edu/~sjanssen/Keeping%20the%20Symbols%20Straight.pdf).